# "Non-system disk" error when trying to boot from usb

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on an ancient Dell Inspiron Mini which is already running an ancient version of Ubuntu (10.10 Maverick Meerkat). This computer is unable to connect to the internet (I assume because of its obsolete OS), which is why I'm trying to install it via usb drive. I created an installation stick from the Start up disk creator on my other ubuntu machine. The installation version I created is Ubuntu 14.04.0 Trusty Tahr.
I put the usb stick in, restart the machine, and hit F12 to get the boot options. I'm able to select USB Storage. Then I get a screen that says "Non-system disk Press any key to reboot" and then I press a key and it boots from the hard drive.
So I guess my question is this: what is the best way to install Ubuntu on a very old and tiny laptop which has a very old version of ubuntu on it and cannot connect to the internet (and has no CD drive)? There is nothing important on this computer, so I'm fine with just blowing away the entire thing and reinstalling from scratch.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your new Ubuntu installation are not depending on another OS. I think it's about legacy or uefi issue. Is it 64-bit or 32-bit version? Have you tried with another version? Have you checked your bootable USB storage, with another USB Storage?

Comment: It is a 32-bit version. I thought 32-bit would be the way to go since this computer is so old and its brain is so tiny. This is the only version I've tried. How would I check my bootable USB storage with another USB Storage? Should I just make another USB and try that?

Answer (score 1):

I reformatted the USB stick and put a new installation on it using the 64 bit version (this guy: ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso). I was able to boot from the USB drive with that.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the 'Recovery' partition on Windows or another OS that has a boot kernel to try to load it into an operating system. For example, a Windows 7 installer via USB to an installation of Windows Vista will work. Though Windows Vista doesn't recognize the Ubuntu installer, as it is Linux based. What I did is I got a USB installer of Windows 7, went to the Install page, deleted both the 'C:\' drive and the 'Recovery' drive, then removed the USB and restarted. I inserted the Ubuntu USB installer and it worked perfectly. I hope this helps!